# Central backup server?

Tags: linux, backup

We've got a bunch of Linux and Windows Servers that I'd like to do full-system backups of -- to a centralized Linux Server.

Ideally we'd have de-duping and versioning; but it's not required.

I haven't found any great solutions out there in the freeware or small business cost size -- any recommendations?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I would consider two open-source solutions-

- bacula

This is a very modular application/service but it will work consistently and easily once in place.

Pay attention to the last third of the link page below with the bullet point sections, as they scrape away to the real needs/features/shortfalls of Bacula.

http://www.bacula.org/en/dev-manual/main/main/Current_State_Bacula.html

- amanda

Another open-source solution that can run on Linux, but the community addition lacks it's own gui. With the enhanced services and other like-products for sql and cloud, they really, really want you to spend a few bucks on them- they seem pretty geared towards being profitable. Still it's a good application that's been around for years and has a community addition.

http://amanda.zmanda.com/

Comment: Bacula doesn't seem to do full system restorable backups... am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look to [bacula](http://www.bacula.org/en/) - hope it will satisfy your needs

Answer (score 0):

Check out [BackupPC](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/) too. It can back up Linux and Windows. Can deduplicate on file basis. And knows many protocols, like: rsync, samba, ...

Comment: I used to work with BackupPC in my previous job. Very good piece of software. Can even backup dhcp workstations. Very easy restore.